# svn cleanup left my repository inaccessible. Um, what?

Tags: svn, cygwin

Ok, this is actually the second time this has happened and at this very moment I hate svn. I tried executing a commit to svn and for some reason or another the command failed.

```
$ svn ci . -m "some message"
```

It left me with a locked working copy. I spent several minutes trying to figure out exactly what the *best* thing to do here is. I wanted to make sure that the last command that took place was finished, or reverted, or whatever I needed to do. I found this article from the svn documentation that say, essentially "do svn cleanup" http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.cleanup.html. I did that

```
$ svn cleanup
```

Everything went fine then just to make sure everything is fine I do `svn status` again to make sure my working copy is fine and all the locks are removed and all the changed files are still "modified". Ok great. Let's commit again

```
$ svn ci . -m "the same message"
```

Then svn told me to go screw myself

```
svn: E180001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///W:/Codes_Source/(omitted)/trunk'
svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///W:/Codes_Source/(omitted)/trunk'
svn: E000013: Can't open file '/W:/Codes_Source/(omitted)/db/current': Permission denied
```

Huh? Ok, maybe something wierd happened and svn just doesn't know how to tell me. Let me make sure I'm up to date with the repository

```
$ svn up
Updating '.':
svn: E180001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'file:///W:/Codes_Source/(omitted)/trunk'
svn: E180001: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: E180001: Unable to open repository 'file:///W:/Codes_Source/(omitted)/trunk'
svn: E000013: Can't open file '/W:/Codes_Source/(omitted)/db/current': Permission denied
```

The exact same message. Ok, I've spent a little bit of time mucking around with svn. I figure I'll go to the source and find out exactly what's going on.

```
$ svnlook info file:///W\:/Codes_Source/(omitted)/
svnlook: E000002: Can't open file 'file:/W:/Codes_Source/(omitted)/format': No such file or directory
```

eh?

```
$ cd /W\:/Codes_Source/(omitted)/
$ ls -l
d---rwx---+ 1 ssullivan Utilisateurs du domaine      0 Jan 27 13:50 conf
d---rwx---+ 1 ssullivan Utilisateurs du domaine      0 Feb 17 10:12 db
----rwx---+ 1 ssullivan Utilisateurs du domaine    186 Jan 27 13:50 Desktop.ini
----r-x---+ 1 ssullivan Utilisateurs du domaine      2 Jan 27 13:50 format
d---rwx---+ 1 ssullivan Utilisateurs du domaine      0 Jan 27 13:50 hooks
d---rwx---+ 1 ssullivan Utilisateurs du domaine      0 Jan 27 13:50 locks
----rwx---+ 1 ssullivan Utilisateurs du domaine    251 Jan 27 13:50 README.txt
----rwx---+ 1 ssullivan Utilisateurs du domaine 180467 Jan 27 13:50 svn.ico
```

Ok, well it exists, but the permissions look a little funky. I try to confirm what the permissions should be by looking at another repository and they're identical. I can check out the other repository and the other repository works fine. Well let's just check our sanity

```
$ svnlook info .
svnlook: E000013: Can't open file 'db/current': Permission denied
```

What? A different but equally cryptic error. What is going on here? What do you do with an svn repository where you can't even do administrative tasks? How the heck did I break my svn repository?

Answer (score 0):

Your user account does not have enough access permissions to `W:\Codes_Source\`, i.e. to your repositories. It's completely unrelated to running `svn cleanup` against a working copy.